# python 3 find a string that is not followed by a substring

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string that looks like this:

```
line = "aaa farmer's blooper's mouse'd would've bbb"
```

From my string, line, if a word ends with apostrophe or apostrophe + s ('s), then I want to drop apostrophe and s. But I want to keep the word unchanged otherwise.

So, I want my string to be,

```
line = "aaa farmer blooper mouse'd would've bbb"
```

How can this be done using regex expressions?

Comment: A better example for line would be `"aaa abcd' xy'sifs farmer's blooper's mouse'd would've bbb'"`.  This adds an examples with a single apostrophe (which should be removed) and an embedded `'s` (which should not be removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using regex [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to assert what follow by apostrophe, or apostrophe + s ('s) can be whitespace character only or end of string, or in other words, end of words or end of string

```
import re
line = "aaa farmer's blooper's mouse'd would've bbb"
line_new = re.sub(r"'s?(?=(\s|$))", '', line)
# "aaa farmer blooper mouse'd would've bbb"
```

regex explanation

- 's?      # match apostrophe follow by zero or one s
- (?=(\s|$))   # assert what
  follow by can be whitespace character only or end of string

another alternative of the regex would be using negative lookahead to assert what follow by is not any non-whitespace character
`re.sub(r"'s?(?!\S)", '', line)`

Comment: What if the last word ends with `'` or `'s`?

Comment: Yes, `|$`` fixes it.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, modify the answer to handle end of string